# Which Tagging format is the best for training Stanford NER (IO/ IOB)?

Tags: crf

I have trained Stanford NER to extract the organization names from text. I used IO tagging format. It works fine. However, I wonder if changing the tag format to IOB (or other formats) might improve the scores. ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a sentence that lacks normal punctuation, like this:

> John Sam Ted are all here.

If you don't have a B tag you won't be able to tell if this should be three entities or one entity with three words.

On the other hand, for many common types of entities, they can't just run together in normal English text since you'll at least have a comma between them.

If you can set it up, using IOB is better in case you have entities run together, but depending on your data set it may not be an issue. You'll have to look at the data to tell.